# Alternative to the 'or' keyword in PHP

Tags: php, keyword

Right now I have the following code:

```
stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream")
    or die("Failed to register protocol");
```

And I want to do extra stuff before the die in case the function fail. So it raised that  question :

**How does the 'or' keyword works exactly ?**

In many SO questions or answer, I've seen people creating a function, like this :

```
function doStuff() {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die("Failed to register protocol");
}

stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream")
    or doStuff();
```

... but this is kind of unpractical in an Object Oriented context as I don't really want to create a method for that in my object, and I can't yet use closure.

So for now, I've used this code, but I'm not sure that it will have the *exact same behaviour* :

```
if (!stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream") {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die("Failed to register protocol");
}
```

Comment: why you dont use `try catch` block ?

Comment: @Ahmad well, stream_wrapper_register() doesn't throw an exception, and I don't want to create one myself for that specific case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement with "or" works, because the PHP-Interpreter is quite intelligent: 
Because a connection of "or"'s is true, if the first of them is true, it stops executing the statement when the first one is true.

Imagine following (PHP)code:

```
function _true()  { echo "_true";  return true;  }
function _false() { echo "_false"; return false; }
```

now you can chain the function calls and see in the output what happens:

```
_true() or _true() or _true();
```

will tell you only "_true", because the chain is ended after the first one was true, the other two will never be executed.

```
_false() or _true() or _true();
```

will give "_false_true" because the first function returns false and the interpreter goes on.

**The same works with "and"**

You can also do the same with "and", with the difference that a chain of "and"'s is finished, when the first "false" occurres:

```
_false() and _true() and _true();
```

will echo "_false" because there the result is already finished an cannot be changed anymore.

```
_true() and _true() and _false();
```

will write "_true_true_false".

Because most of all functions indicate their success by returning "1" on success and 0on error you can do stuff like `function() or die()`. 
But some functions (in php quite seldom) return "0" on succes, and != 0 to indicate a specific error. Then you may have to use `function() and die()`.

Comment: This is a more complete explanation, so I'll move the check :)

Comment: @EGOrecords, Would `||` work fine too without problems?

Comment: || is equal to "or" and && is equal to "and", so yes it will.

Answer (score 5):

```
a or b
```

is logically equivalent to

```
if (!a) {
    b
}
```

So your solution is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same since `stream_wrapper_register()` returns a boolean value.

Comment: Are there cases where "or die" could be used to handle failure cases that don't return false ?

Comment: You could simply negate the condition that doesn't return false.  In this example it works fine: `$a = true; !$a || die('noes!');`

Comment: or you use "and die();". The reading is quite missleading, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

The two syntaxes are equivalent, and it's just a matter of coding style/preference as to which one you use.  Personally, I don't like `<statement> or die(...)`, as it seems harder to read in most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

THere an "OR" operator available.
the sign is ||

hence, as an example consider:

```
<?php
$count = NULL;

if ($count == 0 || $count == NULL) {
        echo "\nNo Value!\n";
        var_dump($count);
    } else {
        echo "\nSome Value";
    }
?>
```